# How do I select records with duplicates in multiple columns in SQL Server / Excel syntax?

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have the following table:

`[Sheet1$]`:

| Group | Division | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 555 | 2 | Adam |
| 555 | 1 | Bob |
| 444 | 1 | Sarah |
| 555 | 2 | Ann |
| 444 | 1 | Jeff |

I want to select all records from `[Sheet1$]` (I am working with Excel and ODBC) that have the same `Group` and `Division`, but multiple `Names`. I need all 3 columns in the result list.

Result should be like:

| Group | Division | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 555 | 2 | Adam |
| 555 | 2 | Ann |
| 444 | 1 | Sarah |
| 444 | 1 | Jeff |

I have the following query that results in an error:

```
SELECT [Group], [Division], [Name], COUNT(*)
FROM [Sheet1$]
GROUP BY [Group], [Division] 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The above query does not work because of one column not included in the `GROUP BY` clause from my understanding, but between my rusty SQL and ignorance of the MS/Excel SQL syntax, I can't seem to form a valid query for my need. How should I format the correct query?

Comment: The sql-server tag seems irrelevant here.  SQL Server is a database engine server - if you are just querying data in an Excel workbook, then SQL Server is not applicable

Comment: You have columns in your SQL statement that don't correspond with the columns in your sample datasets - so that causes some initial confusion for people who might wish to help

Comment: You've included the "Owner" column in the SELECT clause, but you haven't included the "Owner" column in the GROUP BY clause.  Any columns that you DO NOT include in the GROUP BY clause must have some kind of aggregation function added to them.  For example, you could specific MIN([Owner]), and then your query should run successfully.  Otherwise, if no aggregation applies to [Owner], then you need to add that column to the GROUP BY clause

Comment: i've updated the sample sql for clarity. thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the repeated rows with the individual owners, you'll have to do some in-place concatenation.

```
SELECT [Joint Venture], [Division of Interest], [Owner]
FROM [Sheet1$]
WHERE CONCAT([Joint Venture], [Division of Interest]) IN
(
   SELECT CONCAT([Joint Venture], [Division of Interest])
   FROM [Sheet1$]
   GROUP BY [Joint Venture], [Division of Interest]
   HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
)
```

This is assuming that the ODBC driver for Excel supports the `CONCAT()` method. If it doesn't, you *might* try `[Joint Venture] + [Division of Interest]` in both places if `CONCAT()` doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Jason! Concatenating the two grouped columns worked. The only difference from the above solution was that Excel didn't recognize the CONCAT() function, but using "[Joint Venture] + [Division of Interest]" (or "[Group] + [Division] from the updated post) worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are applying a GROUP BY clause to your SQL statement, then all columns in the SELECT clause - that are not aggregated - must be included in the GROUP BY clause.

So, in your example, you basically have three options.

**Add some kind of "aggregation" to the [Owner] column**

```
SELECT [Joint Venture], [Division of Interest], MIN([Owner]), COUNT(*)
FROM [Sheet1$]
GROUP BY [Joint Venture], [Division of Interest] HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

**Add the [Owner] column to the GROUP BY clause (if you don't want to apply aggregation)**

```
SELECT [Joint Venture], [Division of Interest], [Owner], COUNT(*)
FROM [Sheet1$]
GROUP BY [Joint Venture], [Division of Interest], [Owner] HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

**--or--
Remove the [Owner] column from the SELECT clause**

```
SELECT [Joint Venture], [Division of Interest], COUNT(*)
FROM [Sheet1$]
GROUP BY [Joint Venture], [Division of Interest] HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: I don't think your second option ("Add Owner to Group By clause") would work as that would only return rows with duplicated names. The desired result in the question specifically shows individual names.

Comment: Now that I think of it, your first solution has a similar problem: it only returns one name, not all of them. And your last example doesn't return any names at all. You have provided some good educational information and I wish I could upvote you for that, but this doesn't actually give the OP the result they're looking for.

Comment: @Jason'Bug'Fenter - the OP has since updated the question.  When first posted, the example query that was provided didn't actually match the sample data-sets, so it was difficult to interpret exactly what the expected data outcome was.  Plus, the actual crux of the original question (which is still at the end of the edited question) was that they were specifically getting an error, when trying to run their query, regarding a column not included in the GROUP BY (and that their SQL was "rusty").  I was endeavouring to more broadly clarify the syntax (and options) when using GROUP BY

Comment: @Jason'Bug'Fenter - which makes me wonder .... if an answer is posted to a question, but then the question is edited such that the answer no longer really makes sense for that question, is deleting the answer the correct thing to do?

Comment: good question. I didn't get a chance to see the original form of the question-- only the edited version-- so I couldn't have realized how appropriately you addressed the issue you were presented. Maybe you should edit your answer and put a disclaimer at the top? "The question originally asked about how to use GROUP BY. The question was later clarified. An answer to the original form of the question is provided here." That way, maybe no one downvotes the answer for being irrelevant? Might also be a good point to bring up on the https://meta.stackexchange.com/ site.